# How to call a soap webservice with the "Call HTTP Service" action in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2013, web-services, soap

I'm trying to call this Sharepoint 2013 SOAP WebService from a workflow : https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Sites.asmx

My workflow is hosted on the same sharepoint online farm than the soap WS I wish to call.

My problem is, when I create the action "Call HTTP Service" in Sharepoint Designer 2013, I don't know where to place the SOAP Enveloppe described in the WSDL.

I've started by defining the web service URL as in the screenshot below, but then I don't know what to put in the request parameter because the only thing I can put in it is a dictionnary. And thus I don't know how to put the soap enveloppe in this dictionnary...

Does somebody have tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks !

[image: SharePoint Designer 2013 - Call HTTP Service in a workflow]

Comment: do you get any idea about this? I also face the same problem. I don't know how to put the SOAP envelope in Sharepoint Designer 2013. Regards, Bani

Comment: Nope, I've given up on that idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a soap based web service call. This is a HTTP RESTFul call.

SOAP uses the PUT HTTP method

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of a look into this my self because I wanted the use this to call the list.asmx web service and update the _ModerationStatus column using the UpdateListItems method.

However there is not way to construct a SOAP call, and I've seen a number of articles talking about this issue and it seems that the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action is designed specifically for calling REST web services.

So no you can't call ASMX/SOAP web services using the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action.

Comment: But i reckon you could call a rest api call